# How to compile a bunch of JavaScript files into one file?

Tags: javascript, minimization

I have several JavaScript files and I am wondering how I can process them and generate only 1 JavaScript file. Any tools or some instructions here?

Comment: copy, paste.... how many files?

Comment: quite some, and become more and more in the future.

Comment: try http://www.ryankessen.com/2013/05/how-to-combine-text-files-into-one-with-single-file-with-windows-command/

Comment: There are 100s of ways to do it.

Comment: I must be hungry, I read *brunch*

Comment: @vol7ron Ironically [brunch](http://brunch.io/) as a tool can be used to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking into [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com), a JavaScript task runner. It has a lot of fantastic features and plugins which can automate mundane tasks for you. [Uglify](http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-contrib-uglify/), specifically, sounds like what you're looking for. Uglify compresses multiple JavaScript files into one, while also adding the extra benefits of optimizing your code by removing whitespace and comments. Additionally, it safely renames locally-scoped variables, assigning a shorter (usually one character) variable name instead (as part of the minification process).

You'll have to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) to run it. Grunt also has a command line interface that you'll probably want, [Grunt CLI](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli).

All in all, it takes a decent amount of overhead to get all this set up. But once you have it, it's a fantastic toolset.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use automated tools like Grunt or Gulp like some answers suggest. Or you can use command line if you don't need to do it over and over.

Open command prompt and type
`copy file1.js+file2.js+etc.js combined.js`

Or combine all files in the current directory with *.js* extension
`copy *.js combined.js`

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree with JohnnyRose but would personally recommend [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) over Grunt. It has a few cool features and in development will compile your files on the fly.